How can I set the character to Latn-1 or MCS when using serial-getty?
I'd like to use my old VT420 terminal as system console. Adding RS232 ports and setting up serial-getty are not a problem, but: For years, almost all Linux distros have been using UTF-8 as the standard character set, whereas the VT only speaks Latin-1 (ISO 8859-1) and the old DEC multinational character set.
So: What can I do to make serial-getty use one of the character sets supported by the terminal? Is there an easy-to-implement solution for that? My current distros are:

OpenSuSE Leap 15.6
OpenWRT, current version

Please note that the VT420 does allow to define custom (bitmap) characters, but this is hard work.

getty does not define character sets. The programs you run output whichever bytes they want to output, and most of them use the libc locale system to determine which encoding or charset you want to use – in short, your LANG or LC_CTYPE environment variables. (See the nl_langinfo(3) manual page for more details.)
For example, having LANG=en_US.utf8 or C.UTF-8 indicates that programs should output UTF-8, while plain en_US is usually defined to use ISO-8859-1.
Depending on distribution, extra locales might be either available in locale -a by default or you might need to build them by editing /etc/locale.gen or some other distro-specific magic (dpkg-reconfigure locales, eselect locale, etc), or – if you're running a Musl-based distro – they might not be available at all. (The C locale is always built in, but it defines 7-bit ASCII, not ISO-8859.)
Once you have the en_US locale in the locale -a list, export LC_CTYPE=en_US to override whichever LANG you normally have and run locale charmap to verify the results. (The actual language chosen doesn't really matter much, as LC_CTYPE only influences the charset and nothing else; e.g. date formats will still be based on your LANG.)
Usually LANG is set either through PAM (pam_env) or through the login shell's /etc/profile – again depending on distribution – but tty-specific tweaks like this are probably better done in your ~/.profile or even your ~/.bashrc.
case $TERM in vt[0-9]*)
    export LC_CTYPE=en_US
esac

Not all programs honor the locale character set; some always output UTF-8. In those cases you might need to try the luit "proxy" tool that comes with Xterm (though it normally has the exact opposite purpose – it converts to UTF-8), or try to get tmux or screen to do the conversion.

OK, and which locale would be correct for German? Something like de_DE.latin1?

No, just de_DE. The suffix doesn't directly define the charset; it's part of the locale name. (Like I already said, look at locale -a and /etc/locale.gen for a list of locale names.) For that matter, Latin1 is still Latin1 no matter which language you use it with, so you'll get the same results with LANG=de_DE as you would with LANG=de_DE.UTF-8 LC_CTYPE=en_US.

OK, thank you. Do I also have to change $TERM, as it's now set to xterm-256color?

Yes, but how did that get set to xterm-256color in the first place? That's not what serial-getty@ normally sets it to.

I think that's the standard setting no matter what kind of getty I'm using. I will set it to vt420f for serial-getty.

Well, no – while getty doesn't deal with locale, it does set TERM, usually to the value specified in its command line, or to vt102 otherwise. So if you're getting xterm I'm pretty sure your .profile or .bashrc is setting it to that?

Do you mean something like this: https://www.rogerirwin.co.nz/linux-open-source/enabling-a-serial-port-console/ I'd then replace $TERM with vt420f.
